Typescript not resolving nested node_modules
Summary: Typescript is not detecting types and declarations when they are deeply nested inside node_modules and not at a top level.
Explanation:
I have a package-handler. This handler has some packages as dependencies. One of those packages, let's call it packageA has another dependency, specifically vue-i18n.
When using npm i package-handler, vueI18n is installed at a top level inside node_modules. All declarations and typings are correctly resolved(i.e. $t and $i18n global properties are correctly typed).
When using yarn add package-handler, vueI18n is installed only nested inside
package-handler/node_modules/packageA/node_modules/vue-i18n. This is expected behavior from yarn.
My question is:
Why is typescript not detecting this? Is there a workaround to force it to detect it?
PS:
My package handler works correctly in its case. The only problem I face is this weird Typescript behavior
